# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{a} e^{nx} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Find

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{a} e^{nx} dx$

This seems to be a straightforward problem but since I am new to defnite integrals and thishas appeared in one the graduate exam papers I am looking for proof verification.

My approach:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{a} e^{nx} dx$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{nx}}{n} \bigg|_{0}^{a}$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{na}-1}{n}$

Using L’Hospital’s Rule

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ae^{na}}{1} = \infty$

Please verify the above method, especially the last two steps.

Comment: What if $a<0$?...

Comment: What about $a$. Is $a$ a positive number ?

Comment: nothing is mentioned abt a, calls for two case scenario ... thanks

Comment: It all looks right; I feel it's probably implied that $a>0$, but the case where $a\leq 0$ is just 0. This should be obvious for $a=0$, and the case for $a<0$ puts the exponential on the deniminator, hence the limit of zero.